# Change edittext cursor color and size without xml?

Tags: java, android

I've been working on a practice app where the user can set the color of text and background. But I'm failing to find a way around it

```
android:textCursorDrawable="@null"
```

I've tried this and while it sets the color to the same as the text color it's not what I'm looking to do as I have a specific size set for my cursor.

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <size android:width="10dip" />
    <size android:height="14dip" />
    <solid android:color="#fff" />
</shape>
```

Ive also tried android:color="@null" but that returns nothing ... obviously really (That's a note to my own stupidity).

Finally, I've seen this.

```
 Field f = null;
 f = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
 f.setAccessible(true);
 f.set(editText, R.drawable.cursor);
```

Could i set a color via this way? or is it just a java version of the xml call I already have? Anyhelp would be appreciated.

Basically, to sum up, Id like to set the color of the cursor same as the edit text color but have my height and width of the cursor at 10x14?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check this for cursor color change,

```
public static void setCursorColor(EditText view, @ColorInt int color) {
  try {
    // Get the cursor resource id
    Field field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawableRes");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    int drawableResId = field.getInt(view);

    // Get the editor
    field = TextView.class.getDeclaredField("mEditor");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    Object editor = field.get(view);

    // Get the drawable and set a color filter
    Drawable drawable = ContextCompat.getDrawable(view.getContext(), drawableResId);
    drawable.setColorFilter(color, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN);
    Drawable[] drawables = {drawable, drawable};

    // Set the drawables
    field = editor.getClass().getDeclaredField("mCursorDrawable");
    field.setAccessible(true);
    field.set(editor, drawables);
  } catch (Exception ignored) {
  }
}
```

Comment: How do I call the void? Do I plant it in my oncreate?

Comment: you can call it after getting the edittext Reference by findViewById in Oncreate Method.

Comment: AH! you sir are brilliant. Thanks, bang on works like a treat. Cheers